# ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server: nor preseed nor autoinstall?

Tags: server, 18.04, lts, preseed

I have production-ready packer templates for ubuntu versions 16.04, 20.04 and 22.04 LTS.
I tried preseeding (from ubuntu 16.04 template) and autoinstall (from ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04) without success.

It looks impossible to use the live-server image with any sort of unattended install.
The only possible method for 18.04 is using the "apparently unsupported" ubuntu-18.04.6-server-amd64.iso image. The non-live iso worked fine using a preseed template.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu products using the *year* format (eg. 16, 20 & 22) are specialist *flavors* of Ubuntu 16.04, 20.04 & 22.04 Server and different products with different installation.  I think you meant 16.04, 20.04 & 22.04 but that is different to 16, 20 & 22.  Details matter so please be clear.  (User level apps that run on 16 run identically on 22; which is very different from say 16.04 & 22.04 - different products!)   FYI:  Your issue is likely the different installer; I suggest you look at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Comment: The "live-server" image (which uses *subiquity*) can be automated with autoinstall *starting with 20.04*.  The "server" image (which uses *debian-installer*) can be automated with preseed.  The "server" image was renamed "legacy-server" for 20.04 and is not available for 22.04.  I don't know why you describe the 18.04 "server" image as "apparently unsupported".

Comment: I'm not sure why I came to understand that the "server" image is unsupported..

With "ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso", I wasn't able to re-use autoinstall template ( I have a single packer template working both with 20.04.2LTS and 22.04.1LTS ). I also have a working preseed template for 16.04.7LTS .

The only way I managed to perform an unattended installation of Ubuntu 18.04.6LTS was via pressed using the server (non-live) iso.

My final question is: Which automation method can be used with 'ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso'?

Comment: @MauricioSilveira "Which automation method can be used with 'ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso'?"  There is no automation method for this image.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer @AndrewLowther !
Moving on, I just settled with the non-live image + preseed.
I hope this topic might help others with the same question.
Thanks again!